# How to show price range of custom option in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7, on the product detail price I have some custom option and some configurable product option.

What I want to do is that I want to show the price of the all the option in range, like if lowest total price option is 18.50 and highest total price option is 55.90 than it should show somewhere on product page like "18.50 - 55.90".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are downvoting please also write the reason

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
//load configurable product    
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(some_id);  
//load all children
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                    ->getUsedProducts(null,$product);   
foreach($childProducts as $child){
    $_child = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($child->getId());
    $childPrice =  $_child->getPrice();
    //compare the $childPrice
}
```

or for inline query should be like

```
<?php
    $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $result = $db->query('SELECT a.product_id, a.product_super_attribute_id, ap.product_super_attribute_id, ap.pricing_value FROM catalog_product_super_attribute AS a INNER JOIN catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing AS ap ON a.product_super_attribute_id=ap.product_super_attribute_id WHERE a.product_id='.$_product->getId().' ORDER BY ap.pricing_value DESC LIMIT 1');
    $rows = $result->fetch();
    echo 'From '.Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice()).' to '.Mage::helper('core')->currency($rows ['pricing_value']+$_product->getPrice());
?>
```

**Edit (optional)**

```
$prices = array();
$associated = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProductCollection($_product)
->addAttributeToSelect('special_pric$
foreach ($associated as $assoc) {
    $prices[] = $assoc->getSpecialPrice();
}
if (count($prices)) {
    $min_price = min($prices);
    $max_price = max($prices);
} else {
    $min_price = 0;
    $max_price = 0;
}
```

Comment: this code display same price, as "From € 2.094,00 to € 2.094,00"

Comment: store it in array and make sorting in it. or use my updated answer

Comment: I think there is some error in edited code. syntax is not proper.